# Can I use the display:inline with text-align: right?

Tags: css, xhtml

Example:

```
<td>
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
  <div style="text-align:right display:inline;">
    hello world!
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 18):

Well technically you can but it will have no effect. Display: inline will display the div as an inline element (like an a or span) and therefore not have a width - it will shrink to fit the text.

If you are trying to display inline text on the right try using `float: right;`

Also, in your code you missed out an ";" after the text-align: right.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the element which you want to have display:inline inside another div with dir="rtl"

```
<div dir="rtl">
  <div style="display: inline">Align to the right</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/guya/xwhodc0s/

Answer (score 0):

The spec is somewhat unclear on this, but it shouldn't work. The `text-align` property doesn't really make sense on inline elements, since it applies to blocks of text (which inline elements are not). In your example, `<p>` (a block element) would be a better choice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, but try using display:inline-block; See snippet

```css
.img{
display:inline-block;
}

.text{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: tahoma;
text-align:right;
}

.wrapper{
display:block;
background-color:black;
padding:1em;
width:23em;
}
```

```html
<td>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="..." class="img"/>
  <img src="..." class="img"/>
  <div class="text">
    hello world! Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum loren ipsum
  </div>
</div>
</td>
```