# Can I append inline elements and align them to the left?

Tags: javascript, css, inline, display

I am appending h4 elements to a div with the class of `teamDisplay`. I want the appended elements to be centered on the page but aligned to the left. For example, I want the alignment to look like this (aligned left)

```
            4. New York Giants
            5. Green Bay Packers
            6. Buffalo Bills
```

however, the appended elements are currently aligning to the center like so

```
           4. New York Giants
          5. Green Bay Packers
            6. Buffalo Bills
```

I have tested removing my `appendInline` class which then aligned everything to the left, however, all the appended elements appeared on separate lines rather than on one single line. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401749/can-i-use-the-displayinline-with-text-align-right/3401775) question, the responders say that `display: inline` and `text-align` wouldn't have any affect together. I thought that I would be able to get past that by wrapping my appended inline elements in a div with `display: inline-block` and `text-align: left`, but to no avail.

```js
// create elements
var teamNumber = document.createElement("h4");
var teamCityName = document.createElement("h4");
var teamMascotName = document.createElement("h4");
...
// assign elements "display: inline" property so they they all appear on the same line when they are appended together. This is where I run into the issue: I want the h4 elements to append on one line (that is why I use inline) and align to the left within the center inline-block div that they are being appended to, but instead they are currently aligning center
teamNumber.className = "appendInline";
teamCityName.className = "appendInline";
teamMascotName.className = "appendInline";
document.getElementById("newFavTeamDiv").append(teamNumber, teamCityName, " ", teamMascotName);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.teamDisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.appendInline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="newFavTeamDiv" class="teamDisplay"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if you understand you question if i am wrong tell me more, you want to inline aling left three h4 element inside div element ?
if you want this try it

`.teamDisplay { display: flex; justify-content:flex-start;}`